# Links don't compile properly on pdflatex

Tags: hyperref, urls

For some reason, I can't get a link to generate when I use the `\hyperref` package with pdfLaTeX compiler. `\hyperref[this is link text]{www.google.com}` yields only a plain unformatted "www.google.com" in the finished document.

I'm running manually installed Texlive 2013 on Linux Mint 16 Cinnamon 32-bit. On a 64-bit Lenovo Thinkpad e420 machine.

Below is a shortened example of the doc I'm trying to compile:

```
\documentclass[letter]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

Here's a hyperref. \hyperref[This is a link to Google]{http://www.google.com}.

\end{document}
```

Output for the above compiles to "`Here's a hyperref. http://www.google.com`" (no hyperlink or link text).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The syntax of `\hyperref` with the optional argument is:

```
\hyperref[<label name>]{<text>}
```

I assume, you do not have `\label{This is a link to Google}`. Then the text "http://www.google.com" appears without link to a non-existing label.

I think you want somethink like:

```
\href{https://www.google.com/}{This is a link to Google.}
```

Then the text "`This is a link to Google.`" is a link to the URL [`https://www.google.com/`](https://www.google.com/).

Comment: That was dumb of me. I read the documentation too quickly and replaced `\href` with `\hyperref`. I was confounded by the fact that `hyperref` is defined, so I didn't get any errors; else I probably would have figured it out sooner.... argh. The simplest things. Thanks again! :-)

Answer (score 8):

From the [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.html) (section **4 Additional user macros**):

> If you need to make references to URLs, or write explicit links, the following low-level user macros are provided:
>
> ```
> \href[options]{URL}{text}
> ```
>
> The text is made a hyperlink to the URL; this must be a full URL (relative to the base URL, if that is defined). The special characters `#` and `~` do not need to be escaped in any way.

So you're after `\href{http://www.google.com}{This is a link to Google}`.